# Bypass Service-Worker caching

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-toolbox

I have a progressive web-app, which speaks to an API. The calls to this api get cached by a service worker, which works great.

But now, I want to add a reload-button, which ideally forces the service worker to try to bypass the cache and update it if successful, also it should not return the cached result if a connection could not be made.

I am a bit unsure how to solve this. I am using the [sw-toolbox](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/).

Comment: Are you caching it in browser cache or indexed db?

Comment: i am using sw-toolbox for this...unsure which way this caches. I am also pretty new to this and don't really know what the difference between those two is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests go through the fetch callback which receives a [request object](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko_sw.js#L58). Thus, before returning a cached response you can [look for an additional](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko_sw.js#L66) header parameter (you need to include it into your request to API) to skip the [logic returning cached response](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko_sw.js#L69).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you are using the application cache. It can be accessed from the app fronted independent of the sw-tool box.

```js
  function onReloadButtonClicked(event) {
      //Check for browser cache support
      if ('caches' in window) {
        //Update cache if network query is successful
        caches.open('your_cache_name')
          .then(function(cache) {
            cache.add('your_url');
          }).catch(function(err) {
            // Do something with the error
          });
      }
    }
```